# Why is the "question eligible for bounty in x hours/days" link not shown when you accepted an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, accepted-answer

When viewing your own question which isn't 48 hours old yet, you'll see a link "question eligible for bounty in *x* hours/days":

[image]

When you accept an answer, the link isn't shown. Is there any particular reason for this? Perhaps you want to give an extra reward to a quick answer; it'd be nice to know when you can actually do so. The 'start a bounty' link is always shown, even if you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 7):

As I see it, that message means "Hey, look! We know you want a good answer, but you have to wait until you can start a bounty" - and if you accepted an answer, it means you already got what you want and it's pointless to nag you further about it with such messages.

That said, I see no harm in the message, so I do support leaving it in place even after answer is accepted.